# How to target element by data attribute using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a div element with a data attribute that I need to use to select that element but I'm drawing a blank on how to do that.

HTML

```
<div class="element" data-id="123456789"></div>
```

JS

```
var element = document.body.querySelector('.element[data-id=123456789]');
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You just need to add `""` on `data-id` value

```
var element = document.body.querySelector('.element[data-id="123456789"]')
```

Answer (score 3):

Add quotes to the attribute selector value:

`var element = document.body.querySelector('.element[data-id="123456789"]');`